# How to implement the pseudocode in the book of semaphores?

Tags: c, pthreads, semaphore, barrier

Lately i followed a course of Operating Systems that sent me to the barrier pseudocode from the little book of semaphores. But for a few hours now i'm struggling to implement this barrier, i can't seem to understand it properly. To understand it, i tried a simple program that lets threads come to barrier, and when all threads arrived, let them pass.
Here's my code:

```c
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <semaphore.h>


#define NR_MAX 5

int n=NR_MAX;
int entered = 0;

pthread_mutex_t mtx;
sem_t smph;

void* bariera(void *v){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
        entered++ ;
    printf("thread %d have entered\n", entered);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
    if(entered == n) { 
        
        sem_post(&smph); printf("Out %d \n", entered);}
    sem_wait(&smph);
    
    sem_post(&smph);
}

int main() {
    pthread_t thr[NR_MAX];
    pthread_mutex_init(&mtx, NULL);
    sem_init(&smph, 0, 1);
    for (int i=0; i<NR_MAX; i  ){
        pthread_create(&thr[i], NULL, bariera, NULL);
    }
    for(int i=0; i<NR_MAX; i  ){
        pthread_join(thr[i], NULL);
        }
    return 0;
}
```

How should this be actually implemented? Cause for now, it only prints the order they arrive at the barrier and then it only prints the last one that arrived.

**EDIT:** Totally forgot, here's the pseudocode:

```
n = the number of threads
count = 0  - keeps track of how many threads arrived at the barrier
mutex = Semaphore (1)  - provides exclusive acces to count
barrier = Semaphore (0) - barrier is locked (zero or negative) until all threads arrive; then it should be unlocked(1 or more)


rendezvous
2
3 mutex.wait()
4 count = count + 1
5 mutex.signal ()
6
7 if count == n: barrier.signal ()
8
9 barrier.wait()
10 barrier.signal ()
11
12 critical point
```

expected output:

```
   Out 5
   Out 4 
   Out 3 
   Out 2
   Out 1
```

(the order doesn't have to be the same)

Actual output:

```
Out 5
```

Comment: "*he barrier pseudocode from the little book of semaphores*". Can't expect everyone to have read or have a copy of the book. Please give the pseudocode in the question itself. Also give the exact expected output vs actual output.

Comment: The pseudo code looks like it has a race condition. `count = count + 1` is safe [mutex protected] but it races against `if count == n` [which refetches `count` but is _not_ mutex locked]. Why don't you [just] use `pthread_barrier_init/pthread_barrier_wait`? Or, if you're trying to reinvent/reimplement them, look at the source for them for a clean/debugged impl.

Comment: I have a task, in order to better understand the semaphores i have to implement this barrier-like pseudocode. Also, i don't think the race condition is a problem now, because all i want is just to print something, as i said, the order doesn't really matter

Comment: Maybe your program should do something after threads pass the barrier so you can see if it's working or not?

Comment: No, the race can prevent it from working correctly. Just do: `temp = ++count;` and then `if (n == temp)`. If you're trying to understand semaphores/barriers, then you should _want_ to understand the race conditions.

Comment: BTW, using `sem_post` to wake up all threads trying to sync on the barrier won't work because it will [AFAIK] only wake up _one_ of the other threads. Unless, you want a "cascade" effect that serializes the wakeup (vs. one thread detects that the barrier is complete and wakes up _all_ threads simultaneously).

Comment: @CraigEstey I think the post after the wait is intended to address that. One thread wakes up, and posts to wake up another thread and so on until all are past the wait.

Answer (score 0):

Three issues:

- Incorrectly initialized semaphore.
- Accessing `entered` outside of the critical section.
- Misplaced `printf`.
- Missing `return`.
- Missing increment in for loops.

```c
void* bariera(void *v) {
    int id = (int)(uintptr_t)v;
    printf("[%d] Before barrier.\n", id);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
    if(++entered == n) 
        sem_post(&smph);  // Wake up a thread.
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);

    sem_wait(&smph);  // Barrier.
    sem_post(&smph);  // Wake up another thread.

    // Do something after the barrier.
    printf("[%d] After barrier.\n", id);

    return NULL;
}

sem_init(&smph, 0, 0);  // Should initially be zero.
for (int i=0; i<NR_MAX; ++i) {
    pthread_create(&thr[i], NULL, bariera, (void*)(intptr_t)i);
}
```

Output:

```
[0] Before barrier.
[2] Before barrier.
[3] Before barrier.
[4] Before barrier.
[1] Before barrier.
[1] After barrier.
[0] After barrier.
[3] After barrier.
[2] After barrier.
[4] After barrier.
```

---

That leaves the barrier semaphore un-reusuable. To fix that because it posts `n+1` times. To leave it back in its original state, we need to post only `n` times.

```c
void* bariera(void *v) {
    int id = (int)(uintptr_t)v;
    printf("[%d] Before barrier.\n", id);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
    if(++entered == n)
        for (int i=n; i--; )
           sem_post(&smph);  // Wake up every thread.
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
    sem_wait(&smph);  // Barrier.

    // Do something after the barrier.
    printf("[%d] After barrier.\n", id);

    return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With C11 atomic types, you actually don't need the separate mutex to protect access to the barrier counter, as demonstrated below. This version also encapsulates the barrier-related variables and operations into a struct and functions, and doesn't require that the last thread to hit the barrier also have to wait on the semaphore.

```c
#include <stdatomic.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

struct barrier {
  int maxcount;
  _Atomic int count;
  sem_t sem;
};

void barrier_init(struct barrier *b, int count) {
  b->maxcount = b->count = count;
  sem_init(&b->sem, 0, 0);
}

void barrier_destroy(struct barrier *b) {
  sem_destroy(&b->sem);
}

void barrier_wait(struct barrier *b) {
  // Atomically subtract a number and return the *old* value
  if (atomic_fetch_sub_explicit(&b->count, 1, memory_order_acq_rel) == 1) {
    // Wake up all waiting threads as they're all at the barrier now
    for (int n = 0; n < b->maxcount - 1; n += 1) {
      sem_post(&b->sem);
    }
  } else {
    sem_wait(&b->sem); // Actual barrier; wake for wakeup
  }
}

void* wait_func(void *vb) {
  struct barrier *b = vb;
  printf("Thread 0x%x before barrier.\n", (unsigned)pthread_self());
  barrier_wait(b);
  printf("Thread 0x%x after barrier.\n", (unsigned)pthread_self());
  return NULL;
}

#define NTHREADS 5
int main(void) {
  pthread_t threads[NTHREADS];
  struct barrier b;

  barrier_init(&b, NTHREADS);
  for (int n = 0; n < NTHREADS; n += 1) {
    pthread_create(&threads[n], NULL, wait_func, &b);
  }
  for (int n = 0; n < NTHREADS; n += 1) {
    pthread_join(threads[n], NULL);
  }
  barrier_destroy(&b);
  return 0;
}
```